# PHP: How do I reference an element whose name I dynamically added using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

this is my second time asking for help here so I hope you don't mind if I make a mistake.

See I have a problem accessing an element (In this case, it's a < td >). I dynamically added it's name using JQuery as I 'echoed' it. I did this because the values inside the table it belongs to, are chosen by the user and is triggered by a button click.

Here's the JQuery:

```
$("#tblAddServices tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(){

     firstCellServ = $("td:first", this).text();
     secondCellServ = $("td:eq(1)", this).text();
     thirdCellServ = $("td:eq(2)", this).text();
     fourthCellServ = $("td:eq(3)", this).text();
})

$('.service').on('click', function(e){

var $table = $("#tblServiceIncluded");

var newTR = $("<tr><td colspan=\"3\" name=\"servID[]\">"+firstCellServ+"</td>
                   <td colspan=\"3\">"+secondCellServ+"</td>
                   <td colspan=\"3\">"+thirdCellServ+"</td>
                   <td colspan=\"2\" class=\"sumService\">"+fourthCellServ+"</td>
               </tr>");

$table.append(newTR);

});
```

Now, I have a PHP script that should be getting the value(s) of the first column of the table which I named 'servID[]'. I am using an array to get its values but I always end up with an Undefined Index warning for the 'servID'.

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['btnSavePack']))
{

    $serviceArray = array();

    foreach($_POST['servID'] as $serviceKey){           
    $serviceArray[] = $serviceKey;
    }

    foreach($serviceArray as $result) {
    echo $result, '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

I hope you someone could help me figure out a way to make this work. I know I could do this with Ajax but I prefer this method since I am only a beginner.  Thank you.

Comment: Only form elements can be posted. Try to convert it to any form element. Or else use AJAX to send your data..

Comment: Please read: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: I'm sorry If I'd been so vague but the table to which this JQuery is appending to, is already enclosed in a form with the post method. It still gives me an undefined index warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the value in an input box with a type hidden.

```
"<td colspan=\"3\"><input name=\"servID[]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\""+firstCellServ+"\"/>"+firstCellServ+"</td>"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. :)